# Preserving equal sized split view

Tags: vim

I start GVIM in not-maximized window mode and split its window horizontally making sure the windows are equally sized. How can I preserve this equal-sized split view when I maximize the main GVIM window? Whenever I maximize GVIM forgets that the windows have been equally split.

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The command to equalize splits is `^W=` (ctrl-W =), or in a script, `wincmd =`.

To do this automatically, you can use:

```
autocmd VimResized * wincmd =
```

Comment: How can I make this auto-trigger itself whenever the size of the main GVIM window changed?

Comment: Place in your vimrc, or run in command-line mode: `autocmd VimResized * wincmd =`

Comment: To restrict this only to diff mode, I put in vimrc `au VimResized * if &diff | wincmd = | endif` Seems to work.